# How to use "› or lrm" in breadcrumb using php?

Tags: php, html

I am implementing this `Dresses › Real Dresses › Real Green Dresses` breadcrumb in `php` but when I use `›` or even `"lrm;"` in html code it is not displaying `"›"` character. So how can this be fixed?

Comment: I didn't understood a bit...

Comment: adding > will show > . whats the issue?

Comment: What did you try? Have you tried concatenation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use html-entities for this. The html-entity for › is `&rsaquo;` - if you replace the sign by this, you should be fine.

Also make sure that you are using UTF-8 for your html-document and php-file, so you can use non-ascii-characters like ›.